# Creating a realistic Kirby

Tags: science-based, creature-design

I've made a more realistic version of Nintendo's Kirby. It has webbed hands and big paddle feet. It has a silly waddle on land but is swift in the water. It is semi-aquatic and can breathe through the skin and through lungs if needed.

It can suck in air (atmosphere on the world I'm putting it on is dense) and expand by using its bellow like lungs to rapidly pump the air into its gap layer beneath the stretchy skin (connected to the main body by flexible scaffolding; the face and limbs do not have this gap). It can then vent out the air through two port holes on the back to get a boost. This is used to defend against predators: to make itself appear larger; to escape by becoming airborne and jetting away. For sucking in prey, they have a filter to keep things from entering the lungs as they suck in, and the lungs are also capable of handling water so they can do this while submerged.

The copy abilities and the able to eat non-stop part have been tossed out, so don't worry about that.

Now what I haven't been able to figure out: Is the creature's round shape realistic? I've never seen any creatures that round on Earth. I was thinking giving them electroreception abilities so they can sense further around themselves to make up for their limited view since they are also a prey species.

Comment: Sucking in the same air as the atmosphere will not allow you to fly.

Comment: One question at a time please! Please choose between "lung morphology" on the one hand or "plausible body morphology" on the other.

Comment: Hmmm, a device which sucks in air continuously, expands it by adding heat, and propels it at high speed through a nozzle at the back... Isn't this called a [jet engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_engine)? How do jet engines work?

Comment: @Halfthawed and indeed Kirby does not fly - he just becomes less dense. He takes big leaps and when full of air he falls slower.

Comment: @Renan Depends on the game, for the most part. They nerfed it in Smash Bros because of you can't have unlimited flight in a game which revolves around ring-outs.

Answer (score 0):

String muscle, a long wire of muscle... Kind of like intestines which can contract on their entire length.

Imagine a string of muscle long 20 meters which can contract down to 10 meters.... That's a lot of suck.

Humans can inhale continuously for a few seconds (just tried it and I can inhale air for 27 seconds)  and we have very small respiratory muscles.

You can arrange the string muscle however you like, random like intestines or maybe in a precise manner and your Kirby should be able to inhale for quite a long time.

And length is not a problem, we are only 1.8 meters on average as humans and have intestines way longer than ourselves.